# Slide show with prioritized loading of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, page-load-time

I am looking for a slide show widget, e.g. as a jQuery plugin. How it should look like, *schematically* (dotted rectangles are images that are not visible initially, navigation via arrow buttons):

```
....  ....       +--+  +--+  +--+       ....  ....
.  .  .  .  [<]  |  |  |  |  |  |  [>]  .  .  .  .
....  ....       +--+  +--+  +--+       ....  ....
```

Requirements:

- The three visible images should load as quickly as possible.
- No typical lazy loading: The initially invisible images should load automatically and
  right away after all visible images have loaded.

Idea: fast initial page load, optimal use of bandwidth, no unnecessary waiting times.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the source to hidden images after page load.

Hidden images:
`<img data-src="/images/image1.jpg">`

After the page load run something like:

```
$(function () {
   $('img[data-src]').each(function () {
       var hImg = $(this),
           src = hImg.attr('data-src');

       hImg.attr('src', src);
   });
});
```

The slide show plugin should be included only after this document.ready function of course.

Comment: Smart! I accept this answer for now since it shows a solution to the problem, albeit with more manual work than anticipated.  *If someone knows a ready-to-use widget that implements this or a similar method and posts it as an answer, I may change my decision.*